# Adding a simple APIKey header to each WCF request on .Net 7

Tags: wcf, .net-7.0

I have added a service reference to a WCF service and the tech support of the API told me a username-password is no longer needed but rather an API key that I have to provide as a header. I have the Key-Value pair for that and successfully tested it in Soup UI.

After looking at a few questions here, I got help up to dotnet core 3.1:

```csharp
// Init client    
grpClient = new CustomerDataService.CustomerDataPortTypeClient(GetBinding(), GetEndpointAddress(config.ServiceUri));

// usage as recommended:
using var ocs = new OperationContextScope(grpClient.InnerChannel);

var requestProp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty { Headers = { [config.ApiHeader] = config.ApiHeader } };
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProp;
var fetchedData = await grpClient.getBrandDetailsAsync();
```

Now, this works for me while in .Net 7 RC2, but I'm also getting solutions recommending not to do this way but instead use an intercepted like-a-so:

```csharp
// Init client 
grpClient = new CustomerDataService.CustomerDataPortTypeClient(GetBinding(), GetEndpointAddress(config.ServiceUri));

// Setup an Interceptor
grpClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new Interceptor());
'''

But I cannot find the `Interceptor` class in .Net 7.

Am I setting this up correctly?
```

Comment: Your question is to find other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Yes. I'm exploring the possibility that my way is not the recommended way and writing a custom interceptor is a better approach.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue.

Comment: None @Jiayao . I'm using the first code block. It works fro now until I get a better idea as to whats the best approach to do this.